# iOS: Customizing TableView cell to mimic music player

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Is there an easy way of having a tableview cell like we see here with numbering like this and the border around. Is this created using different sections?

[image]

Comment: Depends on your definition of "easy." There's no magic "make this look like that" property, but if you're comfortable with headers and custom table cells it's not that hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom UITableViewCell.

If you're using storyboards look here:
See this link http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/

If not here is a rundown:
Basically create a new class that inherits from UITableViewCell and a XIB.  Drag a UITableViewCell to the XIB and set it to the class that you created previously.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"CustomCellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
         //*- Load your custom XIB.  objectAtIndex:0 says load the first item in the XIB.  Should be your UITableViewCell that you dragged onto your XIB in Interface Builder.
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    //*- Customize the cell, i.e., cell.myLabel.text = @"Text";

    return cell;
}
```

Using this technique you can layout your cell with three labels, one for the number and one for the name of the song and one for the song time.  Add a background image view for the border and color.

A simple way to get the song number in the table is to use the indexpath.

```
cell.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.row + 1];
```

Comment: I went the route of creating a custom cell class. Wasn´t as time consuming as i feared after all.